# SASS doesn't see variable

Tags: css, sass

I want to add borders determined by `@media` breakpoints. My code is as follows:

```
@media(max-width:767px) { $height: auto; $grid: 1; }
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width:991px) { $height: 370px; $grid: 2; }
@media(min-width: 992px) and (max-width:1199px) { $height: 240px; $grid: 4; }
@media(min-width: 1200px) { $height: 195px; $grid: 6; }

article:nth-child(-n+#{$grid}) {
    border-top: 1px solid #353535;
}
```

SASS returns error `Undefined variable: "$grid"`. But I don't know why. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `$grid` within the scope of the media query and then trying to use it outside of that scope.

As far the SASS compiler is concerned the media queries are redundant at that point so `$grid` doesn't get recognised.

If however the `article` declaration was made inside one of the media queries it would work, likewise if you define `$grid` outside of the media queries it would work.